# How do you eliminate an all divs of a child class but one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div class="city">
  <div class="a">Delete</div>
  <div class="b">Selected</div>
  <div class="c">Delete</div>
</div>
```

**How do you save city and div class b, but delete div class a and c** if you know that the user has selected "b" (you know this using logs your console.log(variable))

Basically what JQuery method would you use to do this and how?

Comment: Your `.a` div has an incorrect closing tag. Forgot the `/`. This will inhibit the success of some of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.city').find('.a, .c').remove();
```

Or

```
$('.city div:not(.b)').remove();
```

[With class variable](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/B5QK9/9/):

```
var selectedClass = 'b';
$('.city div').not('.' + selectedClass).remove();
```

Comment: how can you make this dynamic? Can I pass My_Variable into this?

Comment: I like the `.not('.' + selectedClass)` answer. It seems to be more robust. I might even make it a plugin if it were something i used more than once. `jQuery.fn.removeDivExcept = function(selectedClass){...}`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.city').children('div').not('.b').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your structure, I'd probably use the following:

```
$(".b").siblings().remove();
```

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/akuno3/edit

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.city > div:not(.b)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.city div.b").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().remove()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would do:

```
 $(".b").click(function () { 
  $(".a,.c").remove(); 
});
```